# Как анимировать данный текст?

Tags: html, css

текст, который появляется на пару секунд а потом пропадает ( идея мотивация успех)

[image]

https://toccata.com.ua/

[image: скринвидео анимации]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue)
}

div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
}

div::after {
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: .25;
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
  animation: width-0-100 5s linear;
}

@keyframes width-0-100 {
  from { width:   0;  }
  to   { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div aria-label="ІДЕЯ – МОТИВАЦІЯ – УСПІХ"></div>
```

Comment: А интересно кстати, ну вот, даже на  css  оказывается можно, но на js  как-то мне кажется проще да и возможностей больше.

Answer (score 2):

html/css - никак. Это массив букв типа ['a','b''c]'; которым через js settimeout? Однако я не уверен, что это будет верным решением и все немного сложнее. Нужно будет создать cust sleep(_) по задержке в n.

Мы пробегаемся по массиву строк циклом и на каждой итерации идет задержка.
settimeout обойдет цикл, вот почему нужна функция задержки.

Как-то делал что-то похожие.

```js
const titleTexts = 'EXPOFORUM'.split('');

const linkLogo = document.querySelector('.link');
for (const letter of titleTexts) {
    linkLogo.innerHTML += `<span class="link__letter">${letter}</span>`
}
const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.link__letter');

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

linkLogo.addEventListener('mouseover', async () => {
    for (const letter of letters) {
        await sleep(35);
        letter.setAttribute('style', `color: #000;`);
    }
    letters[letters.length - 1].setAttribute('style', `color: #FFC41E;`);

});

linkLogo.addEventListener('mouseout', async () => {
    for (const letter of letters) {
        await sleep(35);
        letter.setAttribute('style', `color: #fff;`);
    }

});
```

```html
  <div class="expoforum__top">
                    <a class="expoforum__logo  link" href="#"></a>
                    <nav class="expoforum__navigation navigation center-items"></nav>
                    <div class="expoforum__bar center-items">
                        <svg class="expoforum__search-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 612 612"><path d="M606 579L448 423c42-45 67-104 67-170C515 113 400 0 257 0 115 0 0 113 0 253s115 254 257 254c62 0 118-21 163-57l158 156c8 8 20 8 28 0 8-7 8-20 0-27zM257 468c-120 0-217-96-217-215S137 39 257 39c121 0 218 96 218 214s-97 215-218 215z"/></svg>
                        <div class="expoforum__language language">
                            <a class="language__dropdown link center-items" href="#">
                                <svg class="language__dropdown-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 479.4 479.4"><path d="M239 0a240 240 0 100 480 240 240 0 000-480zM78 84l4-4 5-4 4-4 5-4 4-3a187 187 0 019-7l5-4a214 214 0 0146-23l6-2a249 249 0 0111-4l5-1 2-1c-24 23-42 52-51 83-19-5-38-12-55-21v-1zM67 97c19 11 40 19 61 24-11 36-16 74-16 111H16c1-49 19-97 51-135zm0 286c-32-38-50-86-51-135h96c0 37 5 75 16 111-21 5-42 13-61 24zm115 73l-5-1-6-2-5-2a191 191 0 01-27-11l-5-2a223 223 0 01-25-16l-4-3-5-4-4-3-5-4-4-4-5-4-4-4v-1c17-9 36-16 55-21 9 31 27 60 51 83l-2-1zm49 7c-34-4-64-40-83-93 28-6 55-9 83-10v103zm0-119c-29 1-59 4-88 11-10-35-15-71-15-107h103v96zm0-112H128c0-36 5-72 15-107 29 7 59 10 88 11v96zm0-112c-28-1-55-4-83-10 19-53 49-88 83-93v103zm181-23c31 38 50 86 51 135h-96c0-37-5-75-16-111 21-5 42-13 61-24zM297 24l5 1 6 2 5 2a191 191 0 0147 22 210 210 0 0119 14l4 3 5 4 4 4 5 4 3 4 1 1c-17 9-36 16-55 21-10-31-27-60-51-83l2 1zm-50-7c35 5 65 40 84 93-28 6-56 9-84 10V17zm0 119c30-1 60-4 89-11 10 35 15 71 15 107H247v-96zm0 112h104c0 36-5 72-15 107-29-7-59-10-89-11v-96zm0 215V360c28 1 56 4 84 10-19 53-49 89-84 93zm153-67l-3 4-5 4-4 4-5 4-4 3a187 187 0 01-9 7l-5 4a187 187 0 01-10 6l-5 3a238 238 0 01-26 12l-5 2a198 198 0 01-22 7l-2 1c24-23 41-52 51-83 19 5 38 12 55 21l-1 1zm12-13c-19-11-40-19-61-24 11-36 16-74 16-111h96c-1 49-20 97-51 135z"/></svg>
                                <p class="language__dropdown-text" data-toggle="language-dropdown">Russian</p>
                            </a>
                            <div class="language__dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="language__dropdown-link link"  href="#" data-language-id="russian">Russian</a>
                                <a class="language__dropdown-link link" href="#" data-language-id="english">English</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: прошу прощения, ошибки нет? или просто нужно дорабатывать

Comment: Вставил вам  html - где линия, мышкой наведите.

Comment: спасибо, подправил под себя. А возможно сделать так, чтобы по загрузке это происходило? https://jsfiddle.net/n2scmkq9/

Comment: Можно на css. Даже по буквам можно.

Comment: Да можно, где подписываетесь на событие, удалите все включая саму подписку и замените на это. ```(async function main() {
  for (const letter of letters) {
    await sleep(35);
    letter.setAttribute('style', `color: blue;`);
  }
})();```

Comment: Там литералы полетели, где letter.setAttribute('style', - дальше строки должны быть. Почему-то сайт их удалил.

Answer (score 2):

Есть способ "заливки" текста при помощи `-webkit-background-clip: text`. Можно анимировать такой фон:

```css
.text-wrapper{
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  animation: bgFill .5s linear forwards 3.5s;
}
.text{
  background: linear-gradient(orange, orange) no-repeat 0 0/50% auto rgba(255, 165, 0, .3);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  animation: textFill 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes textFill{
  0%{
    background-size: 0 auto;
  }
  75%{
    background-size: 100% auto;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100%{
    background-size: 100% auto;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bgFill{
  from{
    background-image: none;
  }
  to{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://picsum.photos/300/200">
<div class="text-wrapper">
  <div class="text">Ідэя - Матывацыя - Поспех</div>
</div>
```